# ImportError with module pyexcel

Tags: python, python-import, pyexcel

I need to use module pyexcel. So I download it with `pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ pyexcel`

I added `import pyexcel` to my code and try to run it, but I get this message:

```
/home/pem# python2 ./test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyexcel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/pyexcel/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .book import Book
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/pyexcel/book.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyexcel import _compact as compact
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/pyexcel/_compact.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib import request as request
ImportError: cannot import name request
```

test1.py looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import pyexcel
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to install `request` as well

Comment: @SaGaR Unfortunately didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have a `python2` environment but are trying to use `pyexcel` which requires [Python >=3.6](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel/).
Create a `python3.6` or greater environment and it will work fine.

Comment: I've changed version of library. Now it works! Thx)